# How do I platform encrypt custom field from managed package?

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-field, encryption, platform-encryption

I don't see custom fields in `Platform Encryption` Encrypt Fields window.

I know that I can also encrypt only custom fields of these types

- Email
- Phone
- Text
- Text Area
- Text Area (Long)
- URL
- Date
- Date/Time

And I do have such custom fields on my organization but I can't find a way how can I encrypt them.

[This article only says about available types of custom fields for platform encryption but doesn't say anything where I can actually encrypt them.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_custom_fields.htm&type=5)

Can I use platform encryption for field defined in Managed Package installed to my organization?

How can I use platform encryption for custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reach out to our support team to give you the ability to enable encryption on managed custom fields.

Please be aware that by enabling encryption on your custom field, you might prevent further upgrades, in case your package vendor adds non-shield compliant functionality against this custom field.

[Documentation Link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_pe_packages.htm)

**Encrypt Custom Fields in Managed Packages**

> When you install a managed package in your Salesforce org with Shield
>   Platform Encryption, you can encrypt custom fields in the package. You
>   can encrypt any field that belongs to one of the encryptable custom
>   field types.
>
> As an admin, this may increase the range of packages you
>   can leverage, because more packages will be encryption-ready out of
>   the box. (Not all of them, though! Check with the app vendor that a
>   package is compatible with encryption before you install it.)
>
> Important Engage your app vendor to make sure they are prepared to
>   support encrypted custom fields in their package. Then contact
>   Salesforce support to enable this capability for your org.
>
> If you’re an app vendor, talk to Salesforce support about getting set
>   up to support customers who encrypt custom fields used by your
>   package.

Comment: Do you have any documentation where there is clearly stated that Salesforce Support can enable encryption on managed custom fields after opening Salesforce Support ticket?

Comment: These are the release note
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_security_pe_packages.htm

I actually need to go back to our doc writers, it's not clearly specified
We're looking at making it just a preference for admins as opposed to contacting support.

Again, the main thing is that turning encryption on a field has repercussions on upgradability, provided you even can turn encryption on that field in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, this was helpful, I have just updated your answer with the link from your comment

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is possible to set encrypted attribute only for unmanaged custom fields.

If we try to retrieve a managed package custom field and set encrypted attribute on it to true

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableEnhancedLookup>true</enableEnhancedLookup>
    <fields>
        <fullName>CustomPackage__CustomField__c</fullName>
        <encrypted>true</encrypted>
        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Custom Field</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackHistory>true</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Date</type>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

we will receive the following error

> Error: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=Attributes,
>   state=MANAGED_INSTALLED